# How to convert the system to echelon form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\3&2&1\\2&1&2\end{bmatrix}$$

$$s = \begin{bmatrix}15\\28\\23\end{bmatrix}$$

How to convert the above system into echelon form? Replace $A$ and $s$ with the correct values below:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&A12′&A13′\\0&1&A23′\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}s1\\s2\\s3\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first we write the system in the form of $$[A \qquad s]$$
as 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1& 15 \\
3 & 2 & 1& 28 \\
2 & 1 & 2 & 23 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now let's work on the last row to null the first element of it as 
$$r_3 \leftarrow r_3 - 2r_1$$
we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1& 15 \\
3 & 2 & 1& 28 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & -7 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now let's null the first element of the second row as 
$$r_2 \leftarrow r_2 - 3r_1 $$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1& 15 \\
0 & -1 & -2& -17 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & -7 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now let's set the diagonal elements to one starting from the last row
$$r_3 \leftarrow \frac{1}{2}r_3$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1& 15 \\
0 & -1 & -2& -17 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
The second entry of the second row as $$r_2 \leftarrow -r_2$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1& 15 \\
0 & 1 & 2& 17 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Additional: If you want to solve it now, it is easy since we can easily embed the backward substitution method, i.e.
$$s_3 = 5$$
$$s_2 + 2s_3= 17$$
so
$$s_2 = 7$$
and 
$$s_1 + s_2 + s_3 = 15$$
so 
$$s_1 = 15 - (7+5) = 3$$

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you found it useful, you can mark the answer as correct :)